# How to deal with ViewController being released, after firing off background thread which referes to now released ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I have a ViewController which is pushed onto the NavigationController stack. As soon as it's pushed onto the stack it starts to download some images, by means of a downloader object, which is responsible for downlading the images in a background thread.  The images can take several seconds, even over WiFi to download.  When an image has finished being downloaded the downloader object instructs the ViewController to layout its images, putting the newly downloaded image(s) to the back of a paged UIScrollView.  However during this time the user could have pressed the Back button and the ViewController could now have been released / deallocated and so the downloader object will cause a SIGABRT error message and the app will crash.

How should I deal with this situation? Is there some way to check for released / deallocated instances? Or some way to catch the error and log, then ignore, it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a zeroing weak reference.  Of course, with iOS 5.0, this is simply a "weak" reference.  But, if you are targeting below iOS 5.0 though, then you need a custom solution for it.  There is a nice one described by Mike Ash in [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) article.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could avoid the problem by using notifications? Instead of your downloader object referencing the viewController, it posts a notification, which the viewController (if it's loaded) responds to.

in your data loading object:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"allDataLoaded" object:nil];
```

in your view controller viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshMyLayout) name:@"allDataLoaded" object:nil];
```

in your view controller dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

You could even put a reverse notification from your viewController in it's viewDidUnload to tell the data downloader to cancel the downloads (if you want).

Comment: Perhaps in some situations this would be useful, but I actually store the downloaded data in a database, regardless of whether it displays successfully, so terminating the download would actually be counter productive - thanks for the tip though, using notifications instead of delegates might be useful at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to cancel the download once the result is no longer needed. This prevents unnecessary data traffic and memory consumption.

If you can't do that, the downloader object should have some sort of delegate (your view controller probably) that you can set to `nil` when you're no longer interested in the results (e.g. in your view controller's `dealloc` method). Zeroing weak references are also an option, if you target iOS 5, but again, it would be much better to cancel the downloading `NSURLConnection`.